# Fragment mentioned in the activity.xml is not getting displayed in the emulator

Tags: android

I have created two fragment classes and then in the activity_main.xml I have mentioned two fragment tags and have mentioned the name attribute as well.

FragmentClass;

```
package com.example.hsports.fragmentsinandroid;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by I324671 on 8/27/2016.
 */
public class FragmentClass extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout,container,false);



    }
}
```

FragmentClass2:

```
package com.example.hsports.fragmentsinandroid;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by I324671 on 8/27/2016.
 */
public class FragmentClass2 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout,container,false);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hsports.fragmentsinandroid.MainActivity">



    <fragment android:name="com.example.hsports.fragmentsinandroid.FragmentClass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/firstFrag"
        />
    <fragment android:name="com.example.hsports.fragmentsinandroid.FragmentClass2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/secondFrag"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout used for the fragment is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the first one"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

Now when I am running the code in the emulator then I am just getting the message displayed in the textView just once.
Looks like I am getting the firstFragment printed not the second one.
What should I do print both the fragments?

Comment: Well, the `RelativeLayout` is putting your fragments on top of one another...and both of your fragments have same layout...

Comment: As @Shaishav said you use Relative layout that's why your one fragment over another fragment if you want to display both then follow this http://www.javatpoint.com/android-fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are getting overlapped. Updated code with **layout_below** and **layout_alignParentTop** attribute.

```
    <fragment android:name="com.example.hsports.fragmentsinandroid.FragmentClass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/firstFrag"
        />
    <fragment android:name="com.example.hsports.fragmentsinandroid.FragmentClass2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/secondFrag"
android:layout_below="@+id/firstFrag"
        />
```